# Regular expression to remove everything but the date?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a file named

```
SMITH FAMILY TRUST S09 T90N R42W 30011498002 EXHIBIT USACE 06-24-2013.dwg
```

and I'm looking for a regular expression that will remove everything except the date 06-24-2013.

Below is my code that matches the date itself but I'm unsure how to reverse it.

```
[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}
```

Comment: Why don't you use string manipulation methods?

Comment: What result are you trying to get?

Answer (score 9):

If you keep only the text that is matched, result wil be ignored

```
var match = Regex.Match(yourString, "[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}");
 string result = "";
if(match.Success)
 result = match.Value;
```

result will give you this 06-24-2013. Which means rest is ignored.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is with lookahead and lookbehind anchors: this expression

```
"SMITH FAMILY TRUST S09 T90N R42W 30011498002 EXHIBIT USACE 06-24-2013.dwg"
.replaceAll("(?<=[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}).*$|.*(?=[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})", "")
```

returns `06-24-2013` ([demo](http://ideone.com/xa2TAm))

I took your expression for the date, and added it to a construct that matches everything up to, but not including, your expression from both ends. When this construct is used in a call of `replaceAll`, both sides end up being replaced. I used empty string as my replacement, so all characters on both sides of your regex end up being removed.

Answer (score 1):

Already been answered, but since I'd started typing:

```
string myString = "SMITH FAMILY TRUST S09 T90N R42W 30011498002 EXHIBIT USACE 06-24-2013.dwg";

string myNewDateString = Regex.Replace(myString, @".*([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}).*", "$1");

Console.WriteLine(myNewString); // 06-24-2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the date in a variable called `dateStr`:

```
string newName = dateStr + ".dwg";
```

Or were you trying to remove only the date, e.g. to get the result `SMITH FAMILY TRUST S09 T90N R42W 30011498002 EXHIBIT USACE.dwg`?

Comment: Chris M gave exactly what I needed above, thanks for your quick response though

Comment: Yes, that is true. The answer using Regex.Match by Ehsan Ullah, or your own, are more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to revert it if you want to extract it :-)

```
var content = "SMITH FAMILY TRUST S09 T90N R42W 30011498002 EXHIBIT USACE 06-24-2013.dwg";

var result  = content.match(/[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}/g);
if (result)
    console.log(result[0]);
```

This will return 06-24-2013 for you.